# How to approximate job completion times in Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have an application that uses hangfire to do long-running jobs for me (I know the time the job takes and it is always roughly the same), and in my UI I want to give an estimate for when a certain job is done. For that I need to query hangfire for the position of the job in the queue and the number of servers working on it.

I know I can get the number of enqueued jobs (in the "DEFAULT" queue) by

```
public long JobsInQueue() {
    var monitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
    return monitor.EnqueuedCount("DEFAULT");
}
```

and the number of servers by

```
public int HealthyServers() {
    var monitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
    return monitor.Servers().Count(n => (n.Heartbeat != null) && (DateTime.Now - n.Heartbeat.Value).TotalMinutes < 5);
}
```

(BTW: I exclude older heartbeats, because if I turn off servers they sometimes linger in the hangfire database. Is there a better way?), but to give a proper estimate I need to know the position of the job in the queue. How do I get that?

Comment: Also, it strikes me that you should reword your question to "How to approximate job completion times in Hangfire"

Comment: @TomRedfern: Thanks, Good Idea. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that hangfire is asynchronous, queued, parallel, exhibits an at-least-once durability semantic, and basically non-deterministic.

To know with certainty the order in which an item will finish being processed in such a system is impossible. In fact, if the requirement was to enforce strict ordering, then many of the benefits of hangfire would go away.

There is a very good blog post by @odinserj (the author of hangfire) where he outlines this point: http://odinserj.net/2014/05/10/are-your-methods-ready-to-run-in-background/

However, that said, it's not impossible to come up with a sensible estimation algorithm, but it would have to be one where the order of execution is approximated in some way. As to how you can arrive at such an algorithm I don't know but something like this *might* work (but probably won't):

```
Approximate seconds remaining until completion = 
    (
        (average duration of job in seconds * queue depth)
        / (the lower of: number of hangfire threads OR queue depth)
    ) 
    - number of seconds already spent in queue 
    + average duration of job in seconds
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of the async way, I just need approximate times. If a job takes one minute (including latency), and I have 12 servers then if I'm 15th in the queue - even if there are 500 jobs - I can assume my job is done in 2-3 Minutes. And although the servers grab jobs whenever they can, I don't think they grab them randomly, there is an ordering in the jobs, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @EluciusFTW - it depends on how hangfire decides which jobs get processed next in a multi-server environment. It could be as simple as the oldest unprocessed job gets done next, but it could be more complex behaviour. I suppose one way of finding this information out would be to query hangfire DB. However, this is not very futureproof.

Comment: @EluciusFTW - if you do manage to come up with a method which works, remember to post it here. I'd love to use it in the future!